# SSIS scheduled job not found under SQL Server Agent --> Jobs

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 that is running on a schedule. When i choose Integration Services Catalogs --> XXXDB --> Project --> Packages --> Right Click on the .dtsx file --> Reports --> Standard Reports --> All executions :

I see the package has been running successfully on the correct schedule. But, I dont see the scheduled job under SQL Server Agent --> Jobs. How is it possible ?

Comment: Is it running as a "Package Source = File System" rather than SQL in the SQL Agent step?

Comment: @MiguelH, Actually, i dont see this job listed under the SQL Server Agent. Not sure how to verify the package source without seeing the job in SQL Server Agent/Jobs. To me it looks like there is no job to schedule this package. But the 'All executions' standard report shows this package history as running successfully

Comment: Windows scheduler? Could be run from a DOS prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!.
It turns out that we have a Development Server and a Production Server. The jobs were getting scheduled even on the development server.

I saw this job listed as running and scheduled on that server. Disabled it and created a new job to schedule it in the production server.